# Read first character of a string with MS Word VBA then delete it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this code that counts the number of characters in a paragraph, and if it is less than `x` word underlines:

```
Sub Underline_Header()

  Dim numOfParagraphs As Integer
  numOfParagraphs = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("NUMBER OF PARAGRAPHS")
  Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

  For x1 = 1 To numOfParagraphs
    Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
    char_count = Len(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range)

    If char_count < 50 Then
      Selection.Font.Underline = True
      'Selection.TypeText Text:="this text" & Selection
    End If

  Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1

  Next x1

End Sub
```

Instead, I am trying to have the macro read the first character of each paragraph, and if it is a `-` (minus sign), then that is the condition to trigger the underline. I have tried:

```
 char1 = Left(Len(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range), 1)
 If char1 = "-" Then
```

But nothing happens.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range, 1)? 
Right() returns characters from Right to Left. Left() returns from Left to Right.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to be skipping through the paragraphs. You never use x1 variable, you always keep selecting the first paragraph. Or am I missing something?

Comment: whoops, yes, Left, but still no result

Comment: +Kris B - well, in the original code (I am trying to modify) in any document, no matter how long it is, the code checks for the len of each paragraph. if it less than so many characters, then it gets underlined - the idea is to find and underline headers in the doc, but instead of checking the len of the para, read the first character of the para, and if it is my var than underline. Same basic routine, just a different qualifying condition.

Comment: You need to use the code from Kris B, not just change Right to Left.  Also, you need to change "Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select" To "Selection.Paragraphs(x1).Range.Select"  You are looping through and selecting the same paragraph every time.

Comment: +OpiedDad and +Kris B -- got it, thanks, Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range, 1) did it

Answer (score 1):

For Posterity, thanks to the posters Kris B and OpiesDad:

```
Sub Underline_Header()

Dim numOfParagraphs As Integer
numOfParagraphs = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("NUMBER OF PARAGRAPHS")
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
For x1 = 1 To numOfParagraphs

Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select


char1 = Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range, 1)
 If char1 = "-" Then

End If

Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1

Next x1


End Sub
```